# From my service how do I listen for when a user clicks on a desktop icon or app from within the application menu?

Tags: android-service

- This question is no longer active - I have been officially notified by the company that we're dropping Android and going with a system that is specifically designed for business use.

In our two sister companies we installed almost 500 android phones assuming they'd have security capabilities similar to Linux that would allow us to provide business phones to our employees but limit their access to apps.  Unfortunately we've since found out that we were hugely mistaken. Android has decided that whoever has possession of the phone should have full access to everything.  Unfortunately for us this has been a business nightmare, with huge data overages, employees downloading and installing anything and everything they can get their hands on from Play Store, the apps we need to run constantly being stopped by the task manager because too many apps are running at the same time with our employees arguing that the apps are buggy or the phone is broken.  Due to our type of operation, the phones are passed from one employee to another often for weeks at a time before a supervisor or technician has access to them.

We absolutely need to either secure the phones or get rid of them.  So...

From within a service, how do I capture when an employee clicks on an unauthorized app either from the desktop or from the applications menu?  I've spent the last 2 days searching Google for an answer, but have turned up nothing.  I know it can be done, because I have a couple of apps on my personal phone that do so.

We're using Android 2.2

Comment: Have you considered this problem to be not a operating system issues, but a personnel issue? Seems like the employees are quite undisciplined. If they don't take in consideration company rules (do not install some things on your work computer, do not install things on work smartphone, etc.), some type of warning/penalty should occur. You could install some kind of activity monitor on the phones, make a list o rules for employees and state to the employees that those are not personal phone, but work phones, and unappropiate usage is work insubordonation.

Comment: Kind of like hiring an alcoholic to be a bartender, and then disciplining him when he leaves work drunk every day?  Ultimately you have to fire him or stop selling alcohol. Forcing families into poverty isn't our first choice. Plus, it isn't my decision.  We're testing non-android tablets.  Ultimately we're going to go with an option that will allow us to avoid firing people while keeping them from accessing unauthorized software from business owned phones/tablets...

Comment: `some type of warning/penalty` does not mean firing people. It means that if you do something bad at work, someone warns you should not due that (like IT or security crew); until you have done it several times and your boss is noticed. Then your boss gives you a warning. Then after several other warnings, your salary gets cut with x% for one month, then with x+y% and if you still don't understand you'll get fired. This is how it works for any kind of insubordonation: missing from work without notice, accessing an area without permission, installing malware on your work computer, etc.

Comment: Did I forget to mention - all 3rd party security apps we install they uninstall almost immediately after the phones hit the field.

Comment: Come on people, focus. I need programming code.  Not a lecture on how to run the company.  How many companies do you know of where the programming geeks have a say over personnel issues? Management doesn't give a hoot what I think about personnel issues. They just want the phones secure.

Answer (score 0):

Why not uninstall Google play store from the phones? And any other apps which are not needed?

Comment: It can be unIstalled if the phones are rooted.

Comment: Rooting 500 phones isn't feasible. Giving rooted phones to our employees isn't going to happen. :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easiest too just install a parental control app. Here's an example, though this particular one may not meet all your needs: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiddoware.kidsplace

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [3CX Mobile Device Manager](http://www.mobiledevicemanager.com/). The sign up process is free and easy. Then you just need to download the app to each phone from GooglePlay and get it set up. I would be interested in knowing if you proceed with it and if it does everything you need it to.

Comment: Package independent 3rd party apps won't work. Our employees are booting the phones into safe mode and then deleting them.  The only app related solution is for us to write our own business software from the ground up, and include security code within that app so the only way they can bypass the security software is to uninstall the app that keeps us in business.  I have a beta version of the app ready to go including monitoring software.  I don't have the code that listens for icon clicks from the main Android Apps menu or desktop icons, which apparently no one here knows how to do.